# JSON Property undefined in JavaScript with p5.js

Tags: javascript, json

I'm just beginning learning to code and this is my first post here so please forgive me if I violate any rules here....
So here is my question, it seems quite simple but I can just not figure out what is the problem. I have a JSON file like this:

```
{"imgj":
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "user_id":"1",
        "tag":"siteplan",
        "imageurl":"images/cb.jpg"          
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "user_id":"2",
        "tag":"floorplan",
        "imageurl":"images/cbb.jpg"             
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "user_id":"1",
        "tag":"section",
        "imageurl":"images/postit.png"          
    },
    {
        "id":"4",
        "user_id":"2",
        "tag":"siteplan",
        "imageurl":"images/avatar_default.jpg"  
    }
]
}
```

and in my .js file, I'm trying to get data of img from the JSON file, but always failed.

```
 p.preload=function(){

                      var url ='imglist.json';
                      imglist = p.loadJSON(url);


                       for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {

                        imgurl = imglist.imgj[i].imageurl;

                        img[i]=p.loadImage("imgurl");
                      }

                    };
```

The result of the console is shown as below:

```
                      console.log(typeof imglist == 'object'); //return true
                      console.log(imglist); //return {} imgj:(4)[{...},{...},{...},{...}]
                      console.log(imglist.imgj[1]); //return undefined
```

it seems that my JSON file is successfully read as an object, but the property of it cannot be read. It's really weird.

Comment: What is `p` and more important `loadJSON` / `loadImage` methods? I can't see actual source of problem.

Comment: You have quotes around "imgurl" in `p.loadImage`, so the path is set to that rather than the value of the variable. Also, you should really add `p5.js` to the tags on your question so it is clear and so that it appears in the p5.js experts feed :)

Comment: There can be many reasons why it doesn't work. Eg when you use `loadJSON`, `imglist` might be not populated yet. If you fetch something it's by default asynchronus, so don't expect it to work. Other reason might be for loop. Try to use `imglist.imgj.map(...)` instead of for loop - `for` can itarate over unexpected values. If console log

Comment: Hi,thank u for comment. they are just functions from p5.js. And I used p because I have two p5 canvas in the same page so i have to call them seperately..

Comment: @sleepy-pen if `loadJSON` is async function, you have to use await or then syntax to run rest of code in right moment.

Comment: What if you `console.log(imglist.imgj)` ? What about `console.log(Array.isArray(imglist.imgj))` ?

Comment: @Zydnar but : `console.log(imglist); //returns { imgj:(4)[{...},{...},{...},{...}] }`

Comment: @JeremyThille yeah, but when it's runned?

Comment: Do you by any chance have the example running in a public p5.js web editor (or another onilne editor)? If so it would be easier to help

Comment: Hi ViggoV, thank u for your answer;) I really made a mistake there. But still it's weird that imglist.imgj[1] showed as undefined.. even if i delete all the other code and just console this item, it still showd as undefined...

Comment: @Zydnar I get your point, maybe this console.log() is ran later, when the loading is finished. But even then why is `imglist.imgj[1]` on next line undefined??

Comment: @JeremyThille it shows "false" and "undefined" ;( really weird that when i console imglist, the imgj is indeed an array...

Comment: `console.log(imglist.imgj)` outputs `false` ??? if not, what does? And `undefined` ?

Comment: You can define function for `Symbol.iterator` for `imglist.imgj` and then  convert it to array `[...imglist.imgj]` if only you can access the properties in some other way... Try also `Object.keys(imglist.imgj)` to see what is untypical about it.

Comment: @ViggoV hi, I just uploaded them to p5 online editor, https://editor.p5js.org/sleepy-pen/sketches/S1uLscXz4  thank u;)

Comment: JSON.stringify returns `{}` there are only few cases when it happens. Eg. when property is of type Symbol or it's not own property...

Comment: @Zydnar then what should I do to solve it..?would it help if I put this JSON data directly in my js file instead of put it as a single file?

Comment: @sleepy-pen this would be be good workaround. Other I have in mind - use own function to fetch JSON, it's only few lines. Or study well examples in documentation. But still I have no idea how to acess it in this context.

Comment: @Zydnar Hi Zydnar, thank u so much for your help! I tired fetch function and now it works! it seems thst the loadJSON function from p5js doesnt work proporly..maybe I should report it ;) thank u again

Comment: @Zydnar oh.....now i can console imglist.imgj, but still not imglist.imgj[0]...:(

Comment: loadJSON sounds like it is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

This should work however it's only fetch workaround. I don't know how to access this not own property made by loadJSON.

```
p.preload= function(){

      var url ='imglist.json';
      fetch(url)
        .then(data=>data.json())
        .then(imglist=>{
             //imglist = p.loadJSON(url);

             console.log(imglist.imgj[0]); // Object { id: "1", user_id: "1", tag: "siteplan", imageurl: "images/cb.jpg" }
             for(let i = 0;i< imglist.imgj.length;i++) {

                 imgurl = imglist.imgj[i].imageurl;

                 img[i]=p.loadImage(imgurl);
             }});

};
```

Comment: hi Zydnar, it seems that all the pics can be indeed loaded with the fetch API, but they can be no longer called (also the length of the array) outside the fetch function...is there maybe ways to solve this? thank u;)

Comment: @sleepy-pen It's because fetch is asynchronous, so you have two ways to solve this - either return whole fetch chain and inside last .then() return desired output, and when calling the preload function use it in same chain way .then... OR use callback in function argument and call it to do your magic.

Comment: Thank u so much Zydnar! I will search for more infos of callback and try to figure it out ;) thanks a lot. really learned a lot from this;)

Comment: To clearify further, this is called a Promise chain. `fetch` returns a Promise (which you should definitely look into). Another option to handle asynchronous code is to use `async` and `await`, which you should also check out.

Comment: @ViggoV thanks a lot for the helpful advice Viggo ;)

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of fiddling I believe loadJSON is actually asynchronous behind the scenes, so your for-loop continues to execute before the file is done loading.

You could store the `imglist` in a global/classwide variable and do the for-loop inside the `setup` or `draw` function instead.

```
var imglist;
var imgs;

p.preload = function() {
  var url = 'imglist';
  imglist = loadJSON(url);
}

p.setup = function() {
  imgs = imglist.map(function(imglistitem) { 
    return loadImage(imglistitem.imageurl); 
  });
}
```

I am not quite sure how p5.js is wired behind the scenes, but the example from the reference uses the `draw()` function to pick apart the json:
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)